# Grid-like layout using TableLayout

Tags: android, xml

I am currently displaying my CardView using TableLayout with 2 TableRows, and the CardView display is from top to bottom, left to right.

However, I would like to further expand and display my elements as illustrated, sort of like a grid. May I know how it can be achieved using TableLayout?

[image: Courtesy of Nestia]